# Textview text not getting displayed properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, textview, android-button

I'm creating a bar graph like structure using buttons and textviews.

I want to display some specific value above each bar.

If the value is within 4 digits, it gets displayed properly but as soon as 5 digit no. comes, text gets wrapped as shown in below screenshot.

I eaven tried `android:singleLine="true"`, but that doesn't change anything.

[image: screen-shot]

**layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:maxHeight="9dp"
        android:minHeight="9dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/shine_btn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Graph01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <com.example.calci.views.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGraph01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />        
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGraph01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"                        
            android:background="#99f" />                
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Graph02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Graph01"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <com.example.calci.views.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGraph02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGraph02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#9f9" />
    </LinearLayout>

<!-- AND SO ON... -->
<RelativeLayout />
```

---

**activity:**

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromTouch) {
lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(20,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lp.setMargins(55, 0, 0, 0);
    tvGraph01.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvGraph01.setTextSize(6);
    tvGraph01.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(20,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lp.setMargins(2, 0, 0, 0);
    tvGraph02.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tvGraph02.setTextSize(6);
    tvGraph02.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, 0, 0.0002f * 2 * progress * 20);
    lp.setMargins(55, 0, 0, 0);
    btnGraph01.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, 0, 0.0002f * 2 * progress * 15);
    lp.setMargins(2, 0, 0, 0);
    btnGraph02.setLayoutParams(lp);
               }
    });
```

---

**MyTextView**

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
// RORARING the textbox as I want to show text at right angle.
        canvas.rotate(270, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

---

I guess prime reason behind this is **setting height of the textview as 20**.
I tried increasing the height of textview, but that increases the space between buttons.
I tried various values of gravity, but that also don't work.

ANY HELP APPRECIATED...

### EDIT

**1).** Anything from .`android:singleLine="true"` or `android:ellipsize="end"` or `android:maxLines="1"`wont work for my cause as I don't want to put **...** for text wrapping.
I want to display the full text.

**2).** Setting `android:layout_height="300dp"` to `LinearLayout` didn't made any difference apart from increase in height of all buttons.

**3).** Setting `android:layout_height="150dp"` to `TextView` didn't made any difference as I'm setting height and width in code.

Comment: try this...increase value of margin in  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

Comment: Use `android:maxLines="1"`

Comment: @GAMA have you tried with posted solution? is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important change which was required : changing `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Graph01` in **LinearLayout with id Graph02** to `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvGraph01"`

i.e. even if textview width increases, corresponding linearlayout won't be affected.

Also, I have to set margins for `tvGraph02`,`btnGraph02`,etc. after increasing width of textview in code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

You are assigning fix height to your `linear graph` layout.

Instead of this:

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Use this:

```
android:layout_height="300dp" or
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change the layout width and height suggestable,and check it will work out

```
 android:layout_width="40px" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your TextView

**android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"**

it will add ' ... ' if text data is more than single line but make sure you will have to set the width of TextView to some values. If you need to keep width as **wrapcontent** than set the paddings to it with some values. Try It.!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this,

   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:maxLength="5"
```